# При движении объектов на экране видны пятна

Tags: железо, монитор

Видеокарта: GTX1080 от Inno3D. Монитор: Asus MG28UQ.

При движении любого объекта на экране начинают появляться чёрные пятна и движутся внутри него.

В целом, я без понятия как это объяснить, но есть фото. (Эта штука меня раздражает, в играх особенно).

Пробовал обновлять драйвера. 
Пробовал менять провода с DP на HDMI.

[image]

Красные овалы - там где появляются пятна при скроллинге вверх-вниз.

P.S. Еще любой текст оставляет за собой тени при скроллинге страниц.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На мониторе был включен trace free, в нем была проблема.

EDIT: Как настроить параметр trace free на мониторе Asus MG28UQ?

1. Включите монитор.
2. Включите меню настройки монитора нажав красный джойстик на правой стороне монитора (сзади корпуса), при этом на монитор должен идти поток HDMI/DP (в данном мониторе иных разъемов под видео-поток не имеется).

Фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. С помощью того же джойстика перейдите к отделу image(Управление джойстиком вверх-вниз). (простите за фото с телефона, принтскрин не захватывает меню).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Свайпните джойстиком вправо, что бы перейти в настройку параметров меню image, далее надо выбрать параметр trace free, перейдите к этому пункту с помощью джойстика (Управление джойстиком вверх-вниз) и заново свайпните вправо.
5. Управлением джойстиком вверх-вниз можно отрегулировать параметр trace free. У меня лично он стоял выше 60, что вызывало артефакты, можете протестировать оптимальное для вашего пк значение этого параметра если хотите использовать такую фичу как trace free (я просто выставил этот параметр на ноль и все артефакты пропали).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6. PROFIT.
7. Что такое trace free и сколько ставить? - http://virtmachine.ru/trace-free-asus-chto-eto-skolko-stavit.html